# Other gas models

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, gas

Are there any other models to explain the behaviour of gases other than the kinetic theory of gas?
Or this is the only theory we have till now to explain the gases.

Answer (score 1):

To accurately describe the behavior of gas molecules, any model must contain at the very least all the assumptions and basic physics that went into the formulation of the original kinetic theory of gases. This tightly constrains the fundamental form that any other dynamical model of gas behavior can possibly take.

Please note that ALL gas theories are approximations to reality which have specific ranges of applicability in which they furnish satisfactory results. For better accuracy in more constrained circumstances (for example, extremely high pressures), the simplified models must be replaced with more sophisticated models that include more physics- which means there is no *single* "kinetic theory", but instead a series of ever-more-complex models which take into full account all the second and third-order  deviations from ideality that the simplest models can safely ignore.